# Using REST API and send POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
POST localhost:5000/registrar

{
  "enrollId": "jim",
  "enrollSecret": "6avZQLwcUe9b"
}
```

How do I use this in a javascript file? Do I use JSON or JQuery? And how do I invoke the request function in .html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jquery for this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And call function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.post('localhost:5000/registrar', {
      "enrollId": "jim",
      "enrollSecret": "6avZQLwcUe9b"
    }, function(serverResponse){

    //do what you want with server response

    })

})
```

Same without shorthand to handle errors:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'localhost:5000/registrar',
  data: {
      "enrollId": "jim",
      "enrollSecret": "6avZQLwcUe9b"
    },
  success: function(){$('#register').html('<h1>Login successfull</h1>');},
  error: function(){$('#register').html('<h1>Login error</h1>');},
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: So if I have a <div id="register"></div> in my .html, all I have to do is $(#register).append(serverResponse) under function(serverResponse)??

Comment: well, i Dont know what you server response is - but if it's html, then yes, you can

Comment: 200 OK
{
    "OK": "Login successful for user 'jim'."
}

This is the supposed response. @Денис Матафонов

Comment: You don't need serverResponse object since it doesnt carry any valuebale info. If you need to handle failed login requests as well - you need to chacnge $.post function to $.ajax (see edit)

Comment: can i call this function in jsp?? if yes how?