# Handling REST request and REST response

Tags: javascript, rest

Just as what the title indicated, how do I handle REST API request and response?

REST request

```
POST host:port/chaincode

{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID":{
        "name": "mycc"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
        "function":"init",
        "args":["a", "100", "b", "200"]
    },
    "secureContext": "jim"
  },
  "id": 1
}
```

REST response

```
2015/11/15 15:19:31 Received INIT(uuid:005dea42-d57f-4983-803e-3232e551bf61), initializing chaincode
Aval = 100, Bval = 200
```

For instance, I have this set of request and response. How do I call the request and use the response to my own usage (e.g. populating a label with the response for interface purpose)? Can I do it using javascript?

Thank you so much for all your help in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: It is possible if you use ajax, there are lots of tutorials online for how to do this.

Comment: @william205 I understand on how to call REST request, however, I am more confused on how to handle the REST response. How do I store variable of Aval or Bval?

Comment: Ah okay, could you post you code for sending the REST request please? Also is the response given to you in JSON, or literally as you have posted it?

Comment: @william205 both the response and request I've already posted on the question itself.

Comment: So that is how you get the response? You don't get it on JSON or some other standard format? Seems odd that a RESTful API would take JSON in but not return JSON.

Comment: @william205 if it's in this format

`message Block {
    uint32 version = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp Timestamp = 2;
    repeated Transaction transactions = 3;
    bytes stateHash = 4;
    bytes previousBlockHash = 5;
}`

is it counted as a JSON format?

Comment: That is not JSON, it looks like Googles own format for sending data to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I managed to find this link, [Using REST API and send POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290552/using-rest-api-and-send-post-request/38290587#38290587) which helped me greatly in REST API.